# MySQL Many to many

Tags: mysql

I am working on a forms submit that is done through php and MySQL. I have one field in the form that lets you associate the new users with a market or markets (select multiple). Now I got my php script to posts values for the new user in the dB, but not connecting that users with markets. I have created a join table that connects the vendors and markets. What I don’t understand is technically the vendor_id can’t be associated with the market_id because it not created yet because the form hasn’t been submitted. Any ideas on how to get around this?  Any help much appreciated! Cheers.

****EDIT****

`
                Choose Market(s)
                
                  Select Market(s)

```
              while ($market = $sql->fetch())
              {
                $selected = $market["market_name"] == $vendor_event ? ' selected' : '';

                echo '<option'.$selected.' value="'.htmlspecialchars($market["market_name"]).'">'.htmlspecialchars($market["market_name"]).'</option>';
              }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>`
```

`$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO vendors (vendor_name, business_name, vendor_city, vendor_state, vendor_phone, vendor_email, certificate_expiration, certificate_number, vendor_type, products_sold, choose_market) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sql->execute(array( $_POST["vendor_name"], $_POST["business_name"], $_POST["vendor_city"], $_POST["vendor_state"], $_POST["vendor_phone"], $_POST["vendor_email"], $_POST["certificate_expiration"], $_POST["certificate_number"], $_POST["vendor_type"],
                      $_POST["products_sold"], $_POST["choose_market"]));`

Then I think I need a query to insert into the 'markets_vendors' table

Comment: Please show us your table structures and what code you currently have.

Comment: If the market_id doesn't exist, then how you could put a list of markets in the dropdown?

Comment: Is a user a vendor?

Comment: If the vendor_id doesn't exist … then the form data contains all the information you need to create it, so what's the problem?

Comment: I have 3 tables rights now: table one is the 'markets' table, table 2 is the 'vendors' table and table 3 it the 'markets_vendors' table. When I go to add a new vendor I have populated a dropdown with the markets, when a user hit 'save' to add a new vendor, a new row in the 'vendors' table is added with the vendor information but i also need a new row added in the 'markets_vendors' table to associate e vendor with particular markets.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple records in one table are related to multiple records in another table.A joining table is a table that sits between the two other tables of a many-to-many relationship. Its purpose is to store a record for each of the combinations of these other two tables.